# R Shiny switch tabPanel when selectInput value changes

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to dynamically switch the active tabPanel in the tabsetPanel when the value of selectInput changes. How would I be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this ought to work:

```
observe({
  updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabsetId", selected = input$selectInputId)
})
```