# How to select a specific tabPanel in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to select a specic tabPanel dynamically in the simply Shiny app. The script of app is as follows:

**ui.r**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("SCORE CARD DEVELOPMENT PLATFORM"),
    navbarPage("ScoreDevApp",
         tabPanel("Settings",
                  fluidRow(column(2,
                                  actionButton("goButton_service", "Load   saved parameters",width=200)
                                  )
                          )
         ),
         tabPanel("Download & Binning input data")
        )
)
)
```

**server.r**:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  #load saved parameters 
  observeEvent(input$goButton_service, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "ScoreDevApp", selected = "Download & Binning  input data")
 })  
})
```

The idea is to press the button **"goButton_service"** and select the tabPanel **"Download & Binning input data"**.

I have used the example from here [R Shiny switch tabPanel when selectInput value changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018242/r-shiny-switch-tabpanel-when-selectinput-value-changes) .

However the tabPanel is not selected. I would be very grateful for your help :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is that you don't have a `tabsetPanel` in your UI (which should be the parent of the two tabPanel). Right now you are using `updateTabsetPanel`, but the target is `navbarPage`.

Working solution below. There were two problems: navbarPage needs an `id`, and also there was an extra space in server.R `selected` (between Binning and input`

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(

    titlePanel("SCORE CARD DEVELOPMENT PLATFORM"),
    navbarPage("ScoreDevApp",
               tabPanel("Settings",
                        fluidRow(column(2,
                                        actionButton("goButton_service", "Load   saved parameters",width=200)
                        )
                        )
               ),
               tabPanel("Download & Binning input data"),
               id="ScoreDevApp"
    )
)
)
```

server.R

library(shiny)

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    #load saved parameters 
    observeEvent(input$goButton_service, {
        updateNavbarPage(session, "ScoreDevApp", selected = "Download & Binning input data")
    })  
})
```

Comment: thanks for comment. I have taken into account your hint.
I have used ' updateNavbarPage(session, "ScoreDevApp", selected = "Download & Binning input data") '. But there is still no results - the targeted panel is not selected. 

P.S.: http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/updateTabsetPanel.html is said that 'updateNavbarPage' is used to select the panel specified.