# R Shiny - How to force execution of Observers

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app with tabs. Some 'Reactive Expressions'/'Conductors' use input coming from several tabs at the same time. The tabs are themselves built with some 'Observers'.

The problem I have is that tabs are only updated when the user selects it and therefore the Reactive Expressions may be called with input that is no longer supposed to exist.

We have found a dirty workaround by triggering some clicks on the tabs to force them to update (using jquery http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).
NOTE: we couldn't use updateTabsetPanel (http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/updateTabsetPanel.html) because it didn't work if we wanted to do somehting like :

```
updateTabsetPanel(session, "myPanel", selected = "Tab1")
updateTabsetPanel(session, "myPanel", selected = "Tab2")
updateTabsetPanel(session, "myPanel", selected = "Tab1")
```

Is there a way to force refreshing/invalidation of Observers that do not have the focus?

Thanks

Comment: I think there is no general answer to this, but I am fairly sure we could find a fix for your special case. Could you provide a (downgraded) code sample that has the same problem you are facing, such that we can experiment a little?

Comment: Well, it  seems to me you have got similar problem as I had - press a button but select a specific tabpanel. If I am correct look at my question and nice answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915016/how-to-select-a-specific-tabpanel-in-shiny).

Comment: I have dealt with similar issues with so success. See this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/kN5tq0co6d0