# How to create a reactive tabsets on Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I'm doing a Shiny App on R, I want to change a filter depends on the "Regiones", It means, I have a tabsetPanel into a TabPanel,

[This is my App now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hVSm.png)

If I click on "Antioquia" my server.R should be

> filter(Base, Base == "Antioquia")

But, If I click on "Bogotá", it should change to

> filter(Base, Base == "Bogotá")

And so on... How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome Dani. Take a look at how to ask - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Always research first. This answer may give you clues - http://stackoverflow.com/q/36915016/4606130

Comment: As that example had no `id` defined for the `tabPanel`, it wouldn't really help him. Most examples don't have it of course...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task is to filter a dataframe reactively when the tabpanel changes. This is harder to figure out than one might think.

In order to do that you have to define an `id` for the `tabsetPanel`, otherwise there will be nothing to "react" to. Since one normally does not need it, most examples don't have that `id` field, and thus it can be hard to stumble across. It is not documented in the help under `?tabsetPanel` for example.

Here is a minimal example that does what you are looking for.

- It creates a `tabsetPanel` with two `tabPanel`s
- the `tabsetPanel` has an `id` called `tabx`.
- It defines a dataframe named `basedf` with two kinds of rows, "A" and "B"
- A filter value is stored as an element in a `reactiveValues` variable.
- It sets that filter when the tab changes (the `input$tabx` statement is necessary for that to happen, otherwise the built-in reactive caching will cause it to be triggered only once).
- There is a reactive output field that filters the `basedf` and prints out what remains.

The code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

basedf <- data.frame(base=c("A","B","A","B","B","A"),val=1:6)

u <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel(h2("TabPanel Test")),
  sidebarLayout(        
    sidebarPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("out1")
    ),        
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(id="tabx",
        tabPanel("tab A", textOutput("outA")), 
        tabPanel("tab B", textOutput("outB"))
      )
    )
  )
))
s <- shinyServer(function(input,output){
  rv <- reactiveValues(curtab=NULL)

  output$outA <- renderText({
    input$tabx
    rv$curfilt <- "A"
    "this is tab A"
  })
  output$outB <- renderText({
    input$tabx
    rv$curfilt <- "B"
    "this is tab b"
  })
  output$out1 <- renderPrint({
    print(sprintf("curtab:%s",input$tabx))
    print(sprintf("curfilt:%s",rv$curfilt))
    ndf <- filter(basedf,base==rv$curfilt)
    print(ndf)
  })
})
shinyApp(u,s)
```

And here is what the output looks like:
[image]